# ¿Como obtener la Latitud y Longitud en api google maps?

Tags: google-maps, google-geocoding-api

Les comparto el código html y JS que tengo ya me hace la búsqueda de la dirección pero quiero que cuando me dirija a la dirección se pueda mover el  marker y que al mover el marker me obtenga la dirección, latitud y longitud y me lo regrese en los inputs

```html
<input id="pac-input" class="controls form-control" name="address" value="{{$data->address}}" type="text" placeholder="Enter a location">
<br>
<div class="row">
<div class="form-group col-md-6"><input type="hidden" name="lat" id="lat" class="form-control" required placeholder="Latitude" value="{{ $data->lat }}"></div>
<div class="form-group col-md-6"><input type="hidden" name="lng" id="lng" class="form-control" required placeholder="Longitude" value="{{ $data->lng }}"></div>
</div>

<div id="map" style="width: 100%;height: 400px;"></div>
<div id="infowindow-content">
  <span id="place-name"  class="title"></span>
  <span id="place-id"></span><br>
  <span id="place-address"></span>
</div>
```

luego creo el script para visualizar el mapa con la api de google maps la cual me retorna la ciudad con el Marker en medio del mapa y tambien me retorna la latitud y la longitud.

```js
<script>
  function initMap() {
    var map = new google.maps.Map(
        document.getElementById('map'),
        {center: {lat: 31.326015, lng: 75.576180}, zoom: 13});


    var input = document.getElementById('pac-input');

    var autocomplete = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(input);

    autocomplete.bindTo('bounds', map);

    // Specify just the place data fields that you need.
    autocomplete.setFields(['place_id', 'geometry', 'name', 'formatted_address']);

    map.controls[google.maps.ControlPosition.TOP_LEFT].push(input);

    var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();
    var infowindowContent = document.getElementById('infowindow-content');
    infowindow.setContent(infowindowContent);

    var geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder;

    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({map: map,
     });
    marker.addListener('click', function() {
      infowindow.open(map, marker);
    });

    autocomplete.addListener('place_changed', function() {
      infowindow.close();
      var place = autocomplete.getPlace();

      if (!place.place_id) {
        return;
      }
      geocoder.geocode({'placeId': place.place_id}, function(results, status) {
        if (status !== 'OK') {
          window.alert('Geocoder failed due to: ' + status);
          return;
        }

        map.setZoom(11);
        map.setCenter(results[0].geometry.location);

        // Set the position of the marker using the place ID and location.
        marker.setPlace(
            {placeId: place.place_id, location: results[0].geometry.location});

        marker.setVisible(true);

        infowindowContent.children['place-name'].textContent = place.name;
        infowindowContent.children['place-id'].textContent = place.place_id;
        infowindowContent.children['place-address'].textContent = results[0].formatted_address;

        document.getElementById('lat').value = results[0].geometry.location.lat();
        document.getElementById('lng').value = results[0].geometry.location.lng();
        infowindow.open(map, marker);
      });
    });
  }
</script>
```

como puedo hacer para que al mover el marker obtener automaticamente la longitud, latitud y la dirección y me los regrese en los inputs de arriba?

Gracias de antemano saludos cracks!

Comment: Lee [ask], edita y agrega como texto el código, idealmente explica tu código y en qué parte ocupas ayuda

Comment: gracias ya edite la pregunta saludos.

Answer (score 0):

Dentro de tu script, podrías agregar este evento:

```
google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'dragend', function(marker){
   var latLng = marker.latLng; 
   currentLatitude = latLng.lat();
   currentLongitude = latLng.lng();
  
   // Colocar currentLatitude y currentLongitude en tus inputs

});
```

Para que este evento funcione, tu **marker** debe tener la propiedad `draggable:true`

```
var marker = new google.maps.Marker({ map: map, draggable: true });
```

Comment: pero cuando le pongo la propiedad draggable:true solo lo hace cuando carga el mapa pero cuando le paso la direccion se queda fijo  y no se mueve el marker :/

Comment: tengo una duda ya logre hacer que me retorne la longitud y la latitud pero como puedo obtener la dirección hay algún método así como el .latLng para obtener el address?

Comment: Genial!  , para obtener el address te recomiendo que utilices `Geocoder`, y con las coordenadas de tu marker podrás hacer una búsqueda y obtener varios datos como la dirección formateada. Aquí hay un [ejemplo de Geocoder buscando por location(lat & lng)](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/geocoding#ReverseGeocoding)